# How int is converted to char and how char is converted to int?

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In the following example the bit representation of byte with all ones is printed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  char c = 255;
  char z;
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    z = 1 << i;
    if ((z & c) == z) printf("1"); else printf("0");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The output is `11111111`

Now we change `char c` to `int c`, so that the example becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int c = 255;
  char z;
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    z = 1 << i;
    if ((z & c) == z) printf("1"); else printf("0");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now the output is `01111111`.

Why the output is different?

**UPDATE**

Compile the following `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char c=-1;
  printf("%c",c);
  return 0;
}

$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out | od -b
0000000 377
0000001
```

The output is 377, which means that glibc contradicts to gcc, because signed char is converted to unsigned char automatically.
Why such complications? It is reasonable to have char unsigned by default. Is there any specific reason why not?

Comment: If you need a specific bit-width use fixed-width types from `stdint.h`. And when shifting it is in general better to use unsigned types, because certain shifts/values on signed integers are implementation defined or even invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first problem here is the `char` type. This type should never be used for storing integer values, because it has implementation-defined signedness. This means that it could be either signed or unsigned, and you will get different results on different compilers. If `char` is unsigned on the given compiler, then this code will behave as you expected.

  But in case `char` is signed, `char c = 255;` will result in a value which is too large. The value 255 will then get converted to a signed number in some compiler-specific way. Usually by translating the raw data value to the two's complement equivalent.

  Good compilers like GCC will give a warning for this: "overflow in implicit constant conversion".

  Solve this bug by never using `char` for storing integers. Use `uint8_t` instead.
- The same problem appears when you try to store `1 << 7` inside a `char` type that is signed on your given compiler. `z` will end up as a negative value (-128) when that happens.
- In the expression `z & c`, both operands are silently integer promoted to type `int`. This happens in most C expressions whenever you use *small integer types* such as `char`.

  The `&` operator doesn't care if the operands are signed or not, it will do a bitwise AND on the "raw data" values of the variables. When `c` is a signed `char` and has the raw value `0xFF`, you will get a result which is negative, with the sign bit set. Value `-1` on two's complement computers.

So to answer why you get different results in the two cases:

When you switch type to `int`, the value `255` will fit inside `c` without getting converted to a negative value. The result of the `&` operation will also be an `int` and the sign bit of this `int` will never be set, unlike it was in the `char` case.

When you execute `-128 & 255` the result will be `128` (0x80). This is a positive integer. `z` is however a negative integer with the value `-128`. It will get promoted to `int` by the == operator but the sign is preserved. Since 128 is not equal to -128, the MSB will get printed as a zero.

You would get the same result if you switched `char` to `uint8_t`.

Comment: `255 & -1` should be changed to `128 & -1`

Comment: see **UPDATE** in OP

Comment: Why they have stolen `char`, instead of creating `int8_t`? Isn't it better when things are called by their name? `char` was meant to store **char**acter codes (i.e., unsigned quantity).

Comment: @IgorLiferenko "255 & -1 should be changed to 128 & -1"  No, it is correct.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko "see UPDATE in OP". Update doesn't make sense. What did you expect the character -1 to be? That code is only going to print nonsense, if anything, no matter the signedness of char.

Comment: "Isn't it better when things are called by their name? char was meant to store character codes (i.e., unsigned quantity)."  The C language wasn't designed rationally. A lot of decisions during the language design and standardization were bad. The problem was that at the point of standardization, some compilers had implement char to behave like the rest of the integer types (signed by default), other compilers had implemented it as a character type (unsigned since character tables dont have negative indices). So they allowed both forms.

Comment: Many of the problems with the C language were actually caused by early ISO standardization. When designing a standard ISO doesn't allow you to give advantages to some technologies over others. That's why C is full of counter-productive rubbish like implementation-defined signedness or "don't assume that a byte is 8 bits".

Comment: "*No, it is correct*" Then "the result will be 128 (0x80)" should be changed to "the result will be 255 (0xFF)"

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Ah, now I see the problem. It should actually be `255 & -128`. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

(*edit to clarify "signed by default"*)

In the first listing, `(z == c)` tests two *char* ; in the second listing however,  `(z == c)` tests one *char* and one *int*.

In order to perform the `&` and `==` operations between a *char* and an *int* the compiler expands the *char* to the size of an *int*.

Regarding the bit 7 (8th):

If your compiler would consider *char* to be unsigned by default, the condition

```
(((int)(128) & (int)255) == (int)128)
```

would render *true*, and a `1` would be printed. However in your case the result is false, and a `0` is displayed.

The reason is likely your compiler that considers *char* to be signed (like gcc by default). In this case, a *char* set to `1 << 7` is actually `-128`, while in an *int* (at least two bytes) 255 is positive.

`(char)-128` expanded to an int is `(int)-128`, thus the condition

```
if ((z & c) == z)
```

reads

```
if (((int)(-128) & (int)255) == (int)-128)
```

which is false in this case.

Comment: `char` is **not** "signed by default" Opposite: the default signed-ness is implementation defined. And the conversion of a too large value to a signed integer is implementation defined, too. As a minor flaw: **all** operands with a lower rank than `int` are converted to `int`. That is not specific to `int` itself being involved.

Answer (score 0):

for char to int, you have to define char as unsigned because by default char or any type is treated as singed.

```
 int main (void)
 {
 int c = 255;
 unsigned char z;
 int i;
 for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
 z = 1 << i;
 if ((z & c) == z) printf("1"); else printf("0");
 }
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: No, char has implementation-defined signedness. It may be either signed or unsigned, it depends on the compiler.

Comment: @Lundin thanks, i did not know about this because i am using gcc compiler only and in gcc it is mentioned "By default char is singed"